# Attributes generation for the XML root element

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am using xmerl's `export_simple` function and I can't find a way to generate attribute for the root `xml` element. I have tried this:

```
defmodule SomeModule do
  require Record
  Record.defrecord :xmlAttribute, Record.extract(:xmlAttribute, from_lib: "xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl")

  def func do
    {:bar, [], []}
    |> List.wrap()
    |> :xmerl.export_simple(:xmerl_xml, [xmlAttribute(name: :encoding, pos: 0, value: :"UTF-8", normalized: true)])
    |> List.flatten()
    |> to_string()

  end

end
```

and it works, it generates the xml, but it does not add the `encoding` attribute for the root `xml` tag.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the callback module that you specified for xmerl is only accepting prolog as an attribute that you can use, and that is where you can stuff anything you need for the prolog:

```
defmodule S do
  require Record
  Record.defrecord :xmlAttribute, Record.extract(:xmlAttribute, from_lib: "xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl")

  def func do
    {:bar, [], []}
    |> List.wrap()
    |> :xmerl.export_simple(:xmerl_xml, [xmlAttribute(name: :prolog, value: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>")])
    |> List.flatten()
    |> to_string()

  end
end

iex(12)> S.func
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><bar/>"
```